# Wordpress post only visible for a set period of time

Tags: php, wordpress

Does anyone know if it's possible to make a wordpress post active for a set period time e.g. 2days and 6hours ?

Maybe we need to use custom field for second date or wp schedule event, cron Linux to delete/hide post ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-expirator/

It allows you to set an expire date along with what to do (e.g. set post to draft, delete post).

The plugin hooks into the wp cron processes and runs every minute by default, but can be configured to use any cron schedule (hourly, twicedaily, daily, etc).